# Memory doesn't make sense

Tags: free

I just checked how much free space I have left on my hard disk using

```
:~$ free -t
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       4063056    1075744    2987312          0      65064     551704
-/+ buffers/cache:     458976    3604080
Swap:      4124668          0    4124668
Total:     8187724    1075744    7111980
```

But how is it possible that I have only 7 GB left while my hard disk is 320Gb?

Also, how can I make space easily and safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`free` talks about RAM -- not hard disk space.

Here, it says that you have 8GB total RAM, about 1GB RAM in use, and 7GB RAM free.

If you want a detailed breakdown of HDD usage, you can use `df`:

```
df -h
```

(df stands for 'disk free' and h for 'human-readable).